# Error while doing character to character matching in java

Tags: java, comparison, character

I'm doing a character to character comparison and checking for some special characters present or not, using the below code, but its not working. Any idea why "ch" comparison with special character doesn't work?

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the password to validate: ");
String pass = sc.nextLine();    

char ch=0;
for(int i=0;i<pass.length();i++)
{
    ch = pass.charAt(i);

    if(ch !='$' || ch !='@' || ch !='#' || ch !='%' || ch !='&')  
      splchar++;
}

if(splchar == pass.length())
    System.out.println("Invalid Password");
else
    System.out.println("Valid Password");
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample input/output for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Did you debug it ? You should know that this is possible with Regex

Comment: @Karan  - For example take input as "Preran1$" which is valid password but displays Invalid Password.

Comment: @Kaustubh Khare - It doesn't work.

Comment: @ AxelH I think my code compiled with no errors, but why it skips the if loop even if i give $ is present in password and prints Invalid Password is beyond my reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is always true

```
ch !='$' || ch !='@' || ch !='#' || ch !='%' || ch !='&'
```

is the same has

```
! (ch == '$' && ch =='@' && ch =='#' && ch =='%' && ch =='&')
```

Since a value can't be `$` and `@` at the same time, this will always be `!(false)` and then `true`.

You want

```
ch =='$' || ch =='@' || ch =='#' || ch =='%' || ch =='&'
```

to check if it is one of those character.

### Alternative - Array

You can simplified your logic using an

```
char[] needed = {
    '@', '$', '#', '%', '&'
};
```

Then you just need to search in that array for a match, since `Arrays` provide those method, you just need to check it with `Arrays.binarySearch(needed, ch)`, it will return the position of the `char` matching or `-1` is nothing is found so you can simplified with

```
if(Arrays.binarySearch(needed, ch) < 0)  
          splchar++;
```

Like *Joop Eggen* said, this need to be a sorted array to work, so you can use

```
`Arrays.sort(needed)`
```

Of course, this become a bit complicated just to search for character, again, *Joop Eggen* proposed a simplified version that work for `char` : `"@$#%&".indexOf(ch) != -1`

### Alternative - Regex

You can use a Regex to match it with your `String` directly. But I will let you do some research on that logic, this is out of context.

Comment: Fine rich answer, but `binarySearch` works only on a sorted array, which `needed` is not. I propose `"@§#%&".indexOf(ch) != -1`

Comment: Yes i'm increasing splchar variable. If you see the if condition after that i'm comparing splchar with pass length. If splchar variable is equal to password length, then definitely there is NO special charater present. Hence it should show "Invalid Password" right?

Comment: @JoopEggen true ! I forgot to add a `Arrays.sort` before ! I adapt the logic I have used before for `String`s that was recover from a file, I should have thought about using a `String` directly... nice suggestion.

Comment: @Sharath your logic is correct, your condition isn't. You can't have a `char` that will be equals with two different character, this is what you have. `ch !='$' || ch !='@' ` = _ch is different of $ or different of @_. So even if this is one of those two, this will still be true, there is no way your condition give a `false` result.